# In Vim, how do I match on "=" but not on "=="?

Tags: regex, vim

I've tried a number of different search patterns:

- `[^=]=[^=]` works but only if = is not at the beginning/end and it also matches the sandwiching characters
- `=\@!==\@!` seems like it should work because \@! matches nothing but requires a match, but it doesn't (see :help pattern-overview)
- `[^=]\@==[^=]\@=` also doesn't but seems like it should

Suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah hah: `=\@<!==\@!`

Comment: For reference, seems that \@<! should be used on the left of a pattern and \@! should be used on the right. It's not obvious that they form a matched pair, but they do.

Comment: FYI, those are `vim`'s version of negative lookbehind and negative lookahead.  In most Perl-derived regex flavors your regex would look like this: `(?<!=)=(?!=)`. ref: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Can you explain your answer to regex newbies?

Comment: `\(...\)\@<!` means «not preceded by ...», `\(...\)\@!` means «not followed by ...». These are zero-width matches: they must be matched, but they do not add symbols to the match.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
[^=]\?\zs=\ze[^=]\?
```

\zs starts the match
\ze ends the match